# what is the standard form for this P.OS (Boolean Algebra)?

Tags: digital-logic

every body
what is the standard form for this P.O.S function
A+A'B+A'C'
my result is
ABC + AB'C' + A'BC + A'BC' + A'B'C'
is this right ?

Answer (score 1):

The unminimized POS form of your function is:

> A+B+C'

The unminimized SOP is:

> A' B' C' + A' B C' + A' B C + A B' C' + A B' C + A B C' + A B C

The minimized form is in this case the same as the POS form.

P.S. The top one you can deduce pretty easily, but I used [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com/) for deducing the other one. Its a pretty neat program to do simple Boolean logic :)

Answer (score 1):

Entering the 3 terms of your first expression (A+A'B+A'C') into a K-map gives:

```
             /--  B  --\
      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
  A   |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |
      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
      |     |  1  |  1  |  1  |
      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
       \--  C  --/
```

, which can be expressed as (A'B'C)' == A + B + C'  .